Sending push notifications with expo
I'm looking for a way to implement push notifications in my React Native app using Expo, but I don't fully understand how the notification chain works.

Can I only work with FCM for notifications, or do I need to add logic for sending notifications to my server (in Java)?

If logic is needed on the server, I just send notification information to FCM, and then FCM sends notifications to my application, or do I need to send notification information directly from my Java server to the application?



Once you create an application on Firebase Console for your android app (after entering the relevant information), you'll get the google-services.json in the final step. This file needs to be added to your expo project and you must specify the location of this file in app.json
Then, you must initialize Firebase in your app and get the FCM token for your device (check out this page). This token needs to be sent to your backend so that it can identify which devices to send the push notifications to via FCM. This implies that on your server, you need to install the appropriate variant of Firebase SDK as well.
To summarize:

Create a new app on Firebase Console
Download the google-services.json file
Initialize Firebase in the app and get the FCM token
Send this token to your server
Use Firebase SDK on your server to send push notifications to all the device tokens registered/stored in your backend

